# Ionic v1 - Native Date Picker's view is not visible(white Screen with Cancel & Select button) in iPhone 7 only?

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

[This is the screen for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siVb8.png)
I'm using below mentioned date picker plugin

> ***plugin name="skwas-cordova-plugin-datetimepicker" spec="~1.0.0"***

This plugin is working in all devices both Android & IOS Platform. But In iPhone 7 only Native date picker is coming like white background with Cancel & Select button.

Please suggest me to resolve this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be due to the dark mode on iPhone. At least it was working for me on my iPhone 7 though I am using ***cordova-plugin-datepicker***. I got it fixed by adding the following lines under `<platform name="ios">` in **config.xml**

```
    <platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="UIUserInterfaceStyle" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>Light</string>
    </config-file>
```

Then run in the console

```
ionic platform remove ios
ionic platform add ios
ionic platform prepare ios
```